# Fullcalendar disable drag & drop but enable editable

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I work a lot of time with a problem.
How to let an event editable, but without enabaling the drag & drop ability.
I may have found a cool solution. Using the "revertFunc();"

```
revertFunc();
```

This function is used for every event by the eventDrop event.
The code is :

```
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        revertFunc();
    },
```

When the event is droped, he cames back to the old position => the drap & drop is disabled, but the possibility to click is still there ^^.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

To disable the drag and drop but still be able to create events you can use the *[eventStartEditable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_ui/eventStartEditable/)*. This worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventStartEditable: false
    });
});
```

Let me know if thats the solution you are looking for :)

Comment: Hum, i'm noob in this web site by posting new subjects.
It was just a question that i had, and un found any answer here.
It was to expose my solution, wasn't really a question.

My problem wasn't to unable the editability of the element, but non draggability.
When you disable the editability of an event, it becames non clickable, and that wasn't my goal. The event has to stay editable to be clickable, BUT non draggable ;-).

Comment: Thats exactly what this does :) it makes it non draggable but clickable :)